# $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ What is $f(A)=B$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$.  I have shown that $f$ is one-to-one on $A$ where $A$ is the set consisting of all $(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ such that $x>0$.  I now have to find the set $f(A)=B$.

I'm not too sure how to go about this.  I am self studying and new to the topics.  After this I will try to find $D_g(0,1)$ assuming that $g$ is the inverse function.  Any hints, tips, or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's one-to-one?

Comment: Consider $f(1,1)$ and $f(-1,-1)$

Comment: it's always the case that $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$

Comment: Um, $x$ and $y$ are not vectors in the definition of $f$ so it isn't defined on $(\vec{x},\vec{y})$. Very confused question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider transforming to polar coordinates ($x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$)

Comment: If you are going to comment, it is helpful to be specific. @Surb

Comment: @Surb Your comment could mean "I don't this approach will give you a solution." It could mean "I don't think this approach is likely useful to the asker." It could mean "I think the problem is wrong." Be specfic. "I don't think it work!" is not helpful.

Comment: Hi - think a comment was made and then deleted since I looked at this page last - is there anything I need to address?